# How to add voice commands to an HoloLens 2 App in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, speech-recognition, keyword, hololens

We are creating a **UWP** app in **Unity**. We are using the **MRTK**. I want to add **voice commands**. If I say "*turn the cube blue*" it should turn the cube blue itself.

Here is what I tried:
Create Empty -> Add the script '*Speech Input Source*' -> Create a Keyword called "*Turn the cube blue*" -> Add the script Speech Input Handler -> Put the Keyword "*Turn the cube blue*" in and get my Cube in the Response () and using my turn blue script.

Now when I say my Keyword, a error pops up.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

When i open that error it gives me this code:

```
InputManager.Instance.RaiseSpeechKeywordPhraseRecognized(this, 0, confidence, phraseDuration, phraseStartTime, semanticMeanings, text);
```

in the **SpeechInputSource** script.

Comment: Did you try breakpoints in order to see what exactly is `null`?

Comment: I've done debug.log with all of these. I found out that semanticMeanings is null

Comment: Two questions from a related [support post](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/1401): Do you have an InputManager in the scene? Do you have the capability "Microphone" enabled in the project settings?

Comment: The microphone is activated and I've the script MixedRealityInputModule on my camera. It doesn't work.

Comment: Could you provide your MRTK version? is it after 2.0? Is your SpeechInputSource script from MRTK? As of today, the latest release of MRTK is 2.3, this is the recommended version and provide new features and fixes some known bugs.

Comment: I use 2.3.0 and the script is from MRTK.

Answer (score 0):

In versions after MRTK2, SpeechInputSource is no longer needed. Instead, keyword of Speech Command must be added to the input system's Speech profile. Please check out the SpeechInputExample scene (in MRTK/Examples/Demos/Input/Scenes/Speech) to understand how to use speech input.

Besides, the [official documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/Speech.html) shows more information about Speech function in the latest version of MRTK, this will be helpful for you.